# show image in table view cell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am trying to show image from sqlite db  in table view cell. I don't know how to achieve this please guide me. I am using below code

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.jpg"];
```

Comment: What is the current results?

Comment: current result is read image from supporting files and show it

Comment: I mean, what do you see on the screen right now? Do you see the cell without the image? You don't see the cell at all?

Comment: I am not aware of the implementation that is reading from database and showing in the cell. I need the code.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `[UIImage imagenamed:@"logo.jpg"]` you are accessing your application directory and not some database. You have to get the raw data from your Database in some way and then convert it to an UIImage.

```
NSData *data = // Get your ImageData here using any Api you want
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

For example you could use this to get Image-Data from an
SQlite-Database:

```
const char *statement = "select ID,NAME,IMAGE from CALL";
sqlite3_stmt *statementCompiled;
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(statementCompiled, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statementCompiled, 2)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: I am using below code I am getting error NSInteger postImageDB = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"post_image"];
    NSData *data =  [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:postImageDB];
    NSLog(@"datas %@",data);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = image;